# created plugin to override the response of customer details

Tags: magento2.2.4

I have created the plugin to override the customer details response based on the token. URL I am using to get customer details is: v1/customers/me

In my plugin folder, I have created a file ModifyUserResponse.php code is as below:

```
namespace Henote\Overrideresponse\Plugin;

class ModifyUserResponse
{
    public function afterGetById(\Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $subject, $result) {
  $modifiedresult=array();

    if($result){
      $modifiedresult['user_details']=$result;
      $modifiedresult['status']=200;
      $modifiedresult['success']=true;
      $modifiedresult['message']="Data Successfully generated";
    }
    echo json_encode($modifiedresult);
    exit;

}


}
```

In my etc/di.xml i have mentioned this class:

I am getting the response in json format but the userdetails are missing and the json array is as below:
``{"user_details":{},"status":200,"success":true,"message":"Data Successfully generated"}

I don't know where I am doing wrong. Please correct me if I am wrong anywhere.

Comment: Hii @ramsai, you need to check the $result variable, you got a null response there, so that's y it's missing in response.
Also, you have to use constructor dependency too.

Comment: I have checked result variable is giving null and also can you give an example about constructor dependency as i am new to magento

Answer (score 0):

> You can do like this.

```
protected $customerRegistry;


public function __construct(
        \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerRegistry $customerRegistry
    ) {
        $this->customerRegistry = $customerRegistry;
    }

public function afterGetById(\Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $subject,$customerId)
{
    $customerModel = $this->customerRegistry->retrieve($customerId);
    $modifiedresult=array();
    if($customerModel){
      $modifiedresult['user_details']=$customerModel;
      $modifiedresult['status']=200;
      $modifiedresult['success']=true;
      $modifiedresult['message']="Data Successfully generated";
    }
}
```

Comment: Please let me know if you still have any issue.